# Navigation bar. Right bar button doesn't animate

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, animation, uinavigationbar, navigationitem

Im adding a right bar button to my navigation bar. It appears and it works fine.

The problem is that it´s not animated. I mean, when I move to other views by clicking in some row, it just suddenly pops out and you can see the new view moving behind it until the sliding animation is finished.

```
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close"style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self    action:@selector(closePopOver)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: closeButton animated:YES];
[closeButton release];
```

And I add it in the `initWithNibName:` method. I´ve tried to move it to the `viewDidLoad` and it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: button items belong to the viewcontrollers that UINav controller manages not to the UINva controller itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specific methods you can use to animate the right bar button items:

`[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: self.addToOrderButton animated:YES];`